# Multiprocessing doesn't work with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, exception, multiprocessing, instagram

**I am being honest, so the reason I use Selenium is because I try to make instagram spam-bot which will send messages to many people where I will ask them to not to be quiet about Russian invasion in Ukraine, because I'm Ukrainian and it's so awful and terrifying what happens around. And this is my duty to help to stop it as mush as I can!**

**Explanation:**
Here is the **multishare()** function which is called from another function that creates **self.followers** set, that contains usernames of people who will be sent text. In multishare() function I redefine self.followers as a list and separate it into 4 equal parts to make spammer four times faster. And then I call **share()** function through the multiprocessing, but it doesn't even open Chrome.
Below you see the code.
Here is the code:

```
    def multishare(self):
        self.followers = list(self.followers)
        ftq = int(len(self.followers) // 4)
        sq = int(len(self.followers) // 2)
        tq = int(len(self.followers) // 1.33)
        fhq = len(self.followers)
        first_part = self.followers[0:ftq]
        second_part = self.followers[ftq:sq]
        third_part = self.followers[sq:tq]
        fourth_part = self.followers[tq:fhq]
        self.followers = [first_part, second_part, third_part, fourth_part]

        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        pool.map(self.share, self.followers)

    def share(self, users):
        self.safe_get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        for user in users:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.safe_get('https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/')
            self.element_existence('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button').click()
            time.sleep(1)
            search_user = self.element_existence('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
            search_user.clear()
            time.sleep(1)
            search_user.send_keys(user)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.element_existence("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.element_existence("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").click()
```

And that's the errors that I got:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=37193): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/5f6dd5e3e048e0bd62e2dd4b1aa5e8ae/timeouts (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa5089d4250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa50c23d1f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=37193): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/5f6dd5e3e048e0bd62e2dd4b1aa5e8ae/window (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa50c23d1f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

So I cant actually solve this. **It's not about multiprocessing, my main target is to make spammer as fast as it possible. So if u have better idea or just know how to solve my issue, help me please !

Comment: what have you tried, and were did you get stuck? The error will have come from somewhere in your `safe_get` method, which is not shown, so we cannot know what's going on there. There is a `retries` keyword argument for many request methods, and also the ability to tune how many redirects are allowed to be followed. you will need to find out why the connection is not being made, which may be related to multiprocessing by hitting a rate limit or quota. It that's the case you are simply making too many requests too fast.

Comment: Instagram will have protections against spamming even if done manually.  I think you want to use threads (don't worry about multi-processing, the browser will handle that nicely) here and make sure each driver/browser instance has it's own.  It looks like you are calling a single one and not waiting for the wire protocol to respond... (include your driver instantiation code)

Comment: I know you feel a sense of urgency here, but a single thread would work fine anyway... but I've done this before on Facebook and after posting the same post to 14 or so different friends' timelines they suspended my account's ability to post for a few days and flagged all the posts as spam.  (They thought I had been hacked...)

Comment: you would have to show how you use Selenium with multiprocesses. Every proces would have to open own browser.